# Why the TestCaseSource is executed before TestFixtureSetUp in Nunit

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I have to create database on the `setup` event and drop into `teardown` event,the flow is working when i have not used `TestCaseSource`.But the moment come i have to used `TestCaseSource` then the execution order of `NUnit` test case is changed.

My database is not created (you can say `setup` event not called),But I have to used `TestCaseSource` for pulling data from table which is created by the `setup` event and dropped into `teardown` .

Please suggest how to deal this type of scenario.I am using VS 2013

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear. Including the relevant test code in your question will make it easier to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are saying is that using TestCaseSource results in attempting to pull data from a database that has not been created yet (in a SetUp method).

This is just the way NUnit works, see https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/141

Maybe you could have TestCaseSource return the query/queries you want to test (instead of the data), and execute the query in the test (after your SetUp has run)?